# Keras Masking for RNN with Varying Time Steps

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to fit an RNN in Keras using sequences that have varying time lengths. My data is in a Numpy array with format `(sample, time, feature) = (20631, max_time, 24)` where `max_time` is determined at run-time as the number of time steps available for the sample with the most time stamps. I've padded the beginning of each time series with `0`, except for the longest one, obviously.

I've initially defined my model like so...

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(max_time, 24)))
model.add(LSTM(100, input_dim=24))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation(activate))
model.compile(loss=weibull_loglik_discrete, optimizer=RMSprop(lr=.01))
model.fit(train_x, train_y, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=1000, verbose=2, validation_data=(test_x, test_y))
```

For completeness, here's the code for the loss function:

```
def weibull_loglik_discrete(y_true, ab_pred, name=None):
    y_ = y_true[:, 0]
    u_ = y_true[:, 1]
    a_ = ab_pred[:, 0]
    b_ = ab_pred[:, 1]

    hazard0 = k.pow((y_ + 1e-35) / a_, b_)
    hazard1 = k.pow((y_ + 1) / a_, b_)

    return -1 * k.mean(u_ * k.log(k.exp(hazard1 - hazard0) - 1.0) - hazard1)
```

And here's the code for the custom activation function:

```
def activate(ab):
    a = k.exp(ab[:, 0])
    b = k.softplus(ab[:, 1])

    a = k.reshape(a, (k.shape(a)[0], 1))
    b = k.reshape(b, (k.shape(b)[0], 1))

    return k.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
```

When I fit the model and make some test predictions, *every sample in the test set gets exactly the same prediction*, which seems fishy.

Things get better if I remove the masking layer, which makes me think there's something wrong with the masking layer, but as far as I can tell, I've followed the documentation exactly.

Is there something mis-specified with the masking layer? Am I missing something else?

Comment: I have a few comments: 1. why have you set a `1e-35` constant when `float32` accuracy is actually `1e-7`?

Comment: In terms of my bounty, I really just want an example of using the masking layer properly for sequences of different lengths. Don't worry about network specifics.

Comment: The `1e-35` comes from here: https://ragulpr.github.io/assets/draft_master_thesis_martinsson_egil_wtte_rnn_2016.pdf , p. 53. It's just to avoid "numerical instability" (as zeroes are undefined here). Think it should be higher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could not validate without actual data, but I had a similar experience with an RNN. In my case normalization solved the issue. Add a normalization layer to your model.

Comment: I apologize for being AWOL on this and I appreciate everybody's input. This was indeed the issue - I had skipped normalization while trying to hack together a minimum viable example, but that was a fatal error. For those interested, the resulting model (different data, though) is here: https://github.com/daynebatten/keras-wtte-rnn

Answer (score 7):

The way you implemented masking should be correct. If you have data with the shape **(samples, timesteps, features)**, and you want to mask timesteps lacking data with a zero mask of the same size as the features argument, then you add `Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(timesteps, features))`. See here: [keras.io/layers/core/#masking](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking)

Your model could potentially be too simple, and/or your number of epochs could be insufficient for the model to differentiate between all of your classes. Try this model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(max_time, 24)))
model.add(LSTM(256, input_dim=24))
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation(activate))
model.compile(loss=weibull_loglik_discrete, optimizer=RMSprop(lr=.01))
model.fit(train_x, train_y, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=1000, verbose=2, validation_data=(test_x, test_y))
```

If that does not work, try doubling the epochs a few times (e.g. 200, 400) and see if that improves the results.